# Sequelize V6 nullable float defaults to 0, should it default to NULL?

Tags: sequelize.js

According to http://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html,

> By default, Sequelize assumes that the default value of a column is NULL. This behavior can be changed by passing a specific defaultValue to the column definition:

I have found that when I `.define` an `amount` column in a table using only

```
    type: Sequleize.FLOAT,
    allowNull: true
  },
```

the column is NOT nullable, and defaults to 0

I found I needed to add a `defaultValue: null` to get the column to default to NULL.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something in the Sequlize documentation? Or is it a sqlite specific bug?

Comment: How exactly did you create a table with this column?